# conditional formatting glitch

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have conditional formatting setup to compare 2 numbers from a form and a subform
it works on some boxes but not on others even though the numbers i'm comparing match 100% and the conditions and the boxes themselves are setup in exactly the same way

the only think i thought was the possible reason is the way the number are formatted (standard, comma, etc) but i see some cases where that can't be the reason

[image: example of the problem]
[image: example of the problem]
[image: example of the problem]
[image: conditional formatting]
[image: conditional formatting]
[image: properties of the top number]
[image: properties of the bottom number]

Comment: Format property does not change value. Format() function results in a string, not a number. So need to cast back to a number to compare with number.

Comment: the FORMAT was from desperation, it doesn't work without it as well

Comment: What doesn't work as well - display or CF rule? Include the unformatted field in a hidden control and reference that in the CF rule.

Comment: The CF expression shows a path for a subsubform. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis. This is more a design than coding issue.

Comment: i will attach the db here tomorrow. CF doesn't work if i just have the field without the FORMAT. i added the FORMAT as something to try but originally i had it without the FORMAT and no luck

Comment: also, yes, it shows a path to a subform but the boxes next to it work and they point to the same subform. also, i have the same issue with CF within the same subform (same db). something weird is going on, will post it soon

Comment: I suggested posting in another forum to provide file. SO wants all info to analyze issue to be within the post, not download files. And I said "subsubform", not "subform".

Comment: could you add a round(yourfield,2) on the relevant formatting fields, just to be sure the nr is the same ?

Comment: @MathiasZ omg, thank you so much!!!! post an answer. don't understand how and why, since i'm rounding these numbers already before they get to the table, but thank you!!!!!